# Effective ways to deploy rcp applications outside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp

Dear all,
I would like to know if there is any best practice or effective way to deploy a set of eclipse osgi bundles (developed with eclipse RCP) outside the eclipse IDE. Up to now we are deploying the plugins with hand-written scripts but this procedure is error prone and time consuming. I discovered the "Plug-In Development -> Product Configuration" approach offered by eclipse but honestly I cannot get it working: in particular I cannot understand what is the correct choice for the Product Application. I tried with org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench but I got errors during the export procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you created an Application class? This is the class that should fire up the Workbench and start your RCP app. The difference between an application and a product is explained [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#overview_product).

Rather than create your Application class from scratch, the easiest way to do it is to create a new "Hello RCP" plug-in project (see previous link), which gives you a basic working RCP app. This will give you the workbench to which your other plug-ins can contribute.

This gives you a product application to select when exporting your product. Choosing "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" as you did will try to export the Eclipse IDE with all its plug-ins as a new RCP app, which is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: That seems exactly what I need. Thanks!